# cannot pass hashset param from jsp to servlet (without session)

Tags: jsp, servlets

i have problem with jsp-servlet. Could you help please?
There are: LoginServlet.java, AddServlet.java, add.jsp, login.jsp.

1. login.jsp, user enter login&password values and go to LoginServlet.java via action.post
2. LoginServlet.java get&check parameters, add to request attributes: *login and empty HashSet* and forward to add.jsp

   ```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
               HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

       request.getSession(false);

       response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

       // Получаем параметры авторизации
       String username = request.getParameter("user");
       String password = request.getParameter("password");

       // Проверяем имя пользователя и пароль
       if ("admin".equals(username) && "123".equals(password)) {

           request.setAttribute("dreamBasket", new HashSet());
           request.setAttribute("user", username);    

           RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(response
                   .encodeURL("add.jsp"));
           rd.forward(request, response);

       }
   }
   ```
3. add.jsp, enter another param and go to AddServlet.java via action.post

   ```
       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
               HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
           request.getSession(false);

       String dr = request.getParameter("dream");

       HashSet dreamBasket = (HashSet) request.getAttribute("dreamBasket"); //NP!

       if (dr != null) {
           dreamBasket.add(dr.toString());
       }
   ```

   }

BUT: AddServlet.java can't see the login and the HashSet attributes (
How can pass login and HashSet values to AddServlet.java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, This is not the way you get values in the `Servlet`.

When you set request scoped attributes in the `Servlet`, You will get them in `JSP` because you are forwarding the request using same request and response parameters using the `forward(request, response);`

Now, from JSP When you post to a `Servlet`, the `Servlet` container will create a new request so, the values which you have set will be lost.

On a Side Note:  I don't see any reason to create new request scoped `Set` as long as you are not going to use it in the `JSP` you are forwarding.